# Please flag spam as spam; it doesn't matter if it is AI-generated as well

Tags: discussion, flagging, spam

A long-running spam trend is to embed a malicious or merely promotional link inside some block of text, either written by low-wage workers in a spam farm or by stringing semi-random text along automatically. Sometimes they are loosely related to a question topic, otherwise not. Sometimes the link is just snuck somewhere in the block of text, other times it appears as something like "find out more here:" at the end. More recently, this spam trend has been adapted to substitute AI-generated content since this is so easy and cheap.

It doesn't really matter. It's still spam. Flag as spam. We don't need to handle it under any AI policy because it's just spam. I've seen a couple different people raise custom flags about the AI content while others are simply raising spam flags on the same post. The spam flaggers are doing the right thing, but the custom flags won't be seen by the system as validating the spam flags. Flagging as spam will help the content get handled as quickly as possible.

Comment: While [Charcoal's Smoke Detector](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) usually picks them up and helps spam flag them a bit faster, manually reporting ones that are missed will help future ones be more likely to be caught. You can use [SOCVR's Request Generator userscript](https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts) to generate the report message in the chatroom, or do so manually.